# Control Transfer in cmd

Tags: cmd

I am calling an external program, tracd, from a batch file.

```
@echo off                       ::turns the echo off
tracd -s --port 8000 proj_a     ::serves the proj_a wiki
start http://localhost:8000     ::opens the proj_a wiki in browser
```

I want the control to be transferred to the third line after `tracd` is called. However, the control is transferred to `tracd` and the third line will not be reached at all.

How can I modify the script to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the following:

```
@echo off                       ::turns the echo off
start /B tracd -s --port 8000 proj_a      ::serves the proj_a wiki
start http://localhost:8000     ::opens the proj_a wiki in browser
```

What `start` does with the `/B` flag is make a new cmd instance without having it visible.
I have no way to verify if this works since I'm on a Linux system at the moment, but it should be a viable solution..

Comment: Adding the `start /B` to opens the `tracd` in new window, but for some reason closes `tracd` window quickly.